# Java Popup Box not Working

Tags: java, jquery, debugging, popup

I am new to Java, but not so new to programming. In my attempt to familiarize myself with the syntax, I have been slowly developing a sequential program that builds in complexity. I was attempting to add in a popup box, however I have noticed it does not work after I used a scanner, however it does work if I have a pop up box before the scanner! Can someone explain this? I have the pop up box at the beginning commented out. When it is commented out, the code reaches the popup box I am intending to display, which shows "Complete!", but the pop up box never appears and the code never continues on. However, if I uncomment out that initial blank popup box, the second popup box does work and the program continues on as normal.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Tutorial1 
{


static final double PINUM = 3.141592654;        // Declaring a constant

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");

    int myInt = 4, i;            // Declares an integer
    double myDouble;            // Declares Double
    int[] myArray = new int[50]; // Declares Array

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\n\nWelcome! Please enter your name!");
    String userName = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Nice to meet you, " + userName + ".\n");

    System.out.println("\nThe largest float this machine can create is = " + Float.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("\nThe largest double this machien can create is = " + Double.MAX_VALUE);

    System.out.println("\nThis is a test Program for learning Java \nCreated by " + userName 
            + "\n7/29/15\n\n"); // the + carries this line from the last

    myInt++;
    System.out.println("Value : " + myInt);

    myDouble = 4.77;
    myDouble = (myInt-1)/myDouble;

    System.out.println("Value : " + myDouble + "\n");

    for(myInt = 5; myInt >= 0; myInt--)
    {
        System.out.println("Loop Value : " + myInt);
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nTesting Popup box...");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Complete!");

    System.out.println("\n\nTest Done");        
}
```

}

So are there any thoughts on WHY this happens, and how to fix it? I'm hoping to learn and familiarize myself with Java, so be as detailed as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this..

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Tutorial1  extends JFrame
 {


  static final double PINUM = 3.141592654;        // Declaring a constant

public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  JFrame jf=new JFrame();
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");

int myInt = 4, i;            // Declares an integer
double myDouble;            // Declares Double
int[] myArray = new int[50]; // Declares Array

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\n\nWelcome! Please enter your name!");
String userName = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("Nice to meet you, " + userName + ".\n");

System.out.println("\nThe largest float this machine can create is = " +            Float.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println("\nThe largest double this machien can create is = " +   Double.MAX_VALUE);

System.out.println("\nThis is a test Program for learning Java \nCreated by  " + userName 
        + "\n7/29/15\n\n"); // the + carries this line from the last

myInt++;
System.out.println("Value : " + myInt);

myDouble = 4.77;
myDouble = (myInt-1)/myDouble;

System.out.println("Value : " + myDouble + "\n");

for(myInt = 5; myInt >= 0; myInt--)
{
    System.out.println("Loop Value : " + myInt);
}

System.out.println("\n\nTesting Popup box...");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf,"Complete!");

System.out.println("\n\nTest Done");        
}
}
```

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf,"Complete!");   hear you pass JFrame object  as first argument where message dialog show .

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, @mukesh! Your solution worked, mostly. I had to change the javax.swing to a wildcard import in order for it to work, but that fixed the problem I was having. Thanks again!